# Javascript Increase value of textbox +1

Tags: php, javascript, numeric

Basically I'm looking for something in JavaScript for a live webpage that can increase the current numeric value of a text box by 1 each time as a user is typing.

For example

```
<td> <input type='text' name='form_c_port' value='1' size='5' maxlength='5'/> </td>
```

And then my next text box value should be 2 increases by 1 or decreases by 1 everytime the numeric value of the other textbox changes

```
<td> <input type='text' name='form_q_port' value='0' size='5' maxlength='5'/> </td>
```

But I cant seem to find out how to increase the value by one in JavaScript. I know how to do this in PHP, but I need to it to be done on the live webpage as a user changes the value.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/jSXCy/ have a issue with the numeric value staying at 1 if i set the form_c_port value to anything higher than 1 then form_q_port value still remains 1 every time.

Answer (score 1):

This was a lot more complicated than I originally thought. I didn't realize that both inputs could be modified. I finally got it working by listening  for the backspace and delete on the first input. It still has bugs if the input is too fast it seems.

Here is the HTML

```
<td> <input id="one" type='text' name='form_c_port' value='1' size='5' maxlength='5'/> </td>
<td> <input id="two" type='text' name='form_q_port' value='0' size='5' maxlength='5'/> </td>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
var lengthValue = $('#one').val().length;
$('#one').keyup(function(event){
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    var tempLength = $('#one').val().length;
    if(key == 8 || key == 46){
        if(tempLength < lengthValue){
            lengthValue = $('#one').val().length;
            if(isNumber($('#two').val())){
              $('#two').val(parseFloat($('#two').val()) - 1);   
            }
            else{
              $('#two').val(0);    
            }
        }
    }
    else if(lengthValue < 5){
       lengthValue = $('#one').val().length;
       if(isNumber($('#two').val())){
          $('#two').val(parseFloat($('#two').val()) + 1);   
       }
       else{
          $('#two').val(0);    
       }
    }
});


function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

And here is a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/jSXCy/20/).

Comment: Your method actualy works better to what i am trying to accomplish but it has a issue with the fact that if i set form_c_port value to 100 it does not change form_q_port value to 101 it stays at 1 for some reason. http://jsfiddle.net/jSXCy/

Comment: @C0nw0nk I have edited my code to account for this. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/jSXCy/1/)

Comment: It still does the same thing on fiddle for me also i somehow managed to make it output "NaN" by using backspace onit.

Comment: @C0nw0nk this turned out to be a lot more complicated than I thought. I got the above to work it seems for the most part. There are some bugs. Good luck with this. I can't spend anymore time on it.

Comment: Ok much appreciated for your help Blake

Comment: Also if it helps the current working version of this i saw is here http://www.gametracker.com/servers/ you need a account to add servers but it increases and decreases the numeric values correctly

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onkeydown` listener to your input element that will check the current size of the text and update the value.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onkeydown()` event to the objects, so:

```
<input type='text' name='form_q_port' value='0' size='5' maxlength='5' onkeydown="increaseValue(this)"/>
```

Then JS:

```
function increaseValue(object)
{
object.Value += 1;
}
```

Comment: If it worked, please set it as accepted answer so it'll be easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName("form_c_port")[0].value = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("form_c_port")[0].value) + 1
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/NK6dB/